# Sign-Up verification emails going to spam despite proper authentication

Tags: email, spam-filter, spam-marked

I am using SendGrid to relay emails sent via Drupal. I am struggling with Gmail specifically marking Sign-Up verification emails as spam despite using DKIM, DMARC, SPF, reverse DNS, everything there is... I have set up SendGrid to use 2 dedicated IPs.

This does not happen as much with other transactional emails sent via the same CMS (or at least I have not received as many reports from users). So I wonder if it is about the copy of the email (perhaps using the words email and password in the subject?).

Here's the email:

```
Received: by mail-tester.com (Postfix, from userid 500)
    id 22962A0BA9; Thu,  7 Sep 2023 11:36:50 +0200 (CEST)
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.2 (2018-09-13) on mail-tester.com
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No/0.5/5.0
X-Spam-Test-Scores: DKIM_SIGNED=0.1,DKIM_VALID=-0.1,DKIM_VALID_AU=-0.1,
    DKIM_VALID_EF=-0.1,HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_20=0.7,HTML_MESSAGE=0.001,
    SPF_HELO_NONE=0.001,SPF_PASS=-0.001,UNPARSEABLE_RELAY=0.001,
    URIBL_BLOCKED=0.001
X-Spam-Last-External-IP: 149.72.70.96
X-Spam-Last-External-HELO: o2.ptr5494.generation.global
X-Spam-Last-External-rDNS: o2.ptr5494.generation.global
X-Spam-Date-of-Scan: Thu, 07 Sep 2023 11:36:50 +0200
X-Spam-Report: 
    *  0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was
    *      blocked.  See
    *      http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block
    *      for more information.
    *      [URIs: generation.global]
    * -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
    *  0.0 SPF_HELO_NONE SPF: HELO does not publish an SPF Record
    *  0.7 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_20 BODY: HTML: images with 1600-2000 bytes of
    *      words
    *  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
    *  0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
    *       valid
    * -0.1 DKIM_VALID Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
    * -0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from
    *      author's domain
    * -0.1 DKIM_VALID_EF Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from
    *      envelope-from domain
    *  0.0 UNPARSEABLE_RELAY Informational: message has unparseable relay
    *      lines
Received-SPF: Pass (sender SPF authorized) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=149.72.70.96; helo=o2.ptr5494.generation.global; envelope-from=bounces+1455748-9606-test-noj289t8t=srv1.mail-tester.com@email.generation.global; receiver=test-noj289t8t@srv1.mail-tester.com 
DMARC-Filter: OpenDMARC Filter v1.3.1 mail-tester.com 818F8A0BAE
Authentication-Results: mail-tester.com; dmarc=pass header.from=generation.global
Authentication-Results: mail-tester.com;
    dkim=pass (2048-bit key; unprotected) header.d=generation.global header.i=@generation.global header.b=2xi/S5B1;
    dkim-atps=neutral
Received: from o2.ptr5494.generation.global (o2.ptr5494.generation.global [149.72.70.96])
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by mail-tester.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 818F8A0BAE
    for <test-noj289t8t@srv1.mail-tester.com>; Thu,  7 Sep 2023 11:36:45 +0200 (CEST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=generation.global;
    h=content-type:from:mime-version:subject:to:cc:content-type:from:
    subject:to;
    s=s1; bh=VNik7W3spVoPXOL9Pe/iAk8NWnAsTueGVG0bE354jWE=;
    b=2xi/S5B1SjFcxSbsyqf4yBw1DyCg1kdglqBy2llbGUkuxlFMXeTJzCPKUh/7AuregHvS
    PlgUrFWVtst2F5BjSlyb+7IiM6EY0thV8EQlhECkdWXZ/xX6+udHHbQ8uXcsTfB6w4ufvT
    UXnTGrEMUgPlXF/Zi7dq1/bfUCwMg9jW85SMnuyKNJcSW26+h4euaQTCmIKXVdMQax8LMs
    qhMpQ5DJHGaQIE/QBqs/qrJT8ZXf2/CpKRup0+iCBcV/PLHV3TqK7iHBxOHfsRO0C+aZW8
    AIXKVfVfBamTznoqK8pIaP3Pa0nY8OjWtyVdOM1QKDNeyC4f/YCghGagnZhtyyYg==
Received: by filterdrecv-d7bbbc8bf-r6vsn with SMTP id filterdrecv-d7bbbc8bf-r6vsn-1-64F999AB-1
        2023-09-07 09:36:43.122578653 +0000 UTC m=+6193231.319333022
Received: from MTQ1NTc0OA (unknown)
    by geopod-ismtpd-5 (SG) with HTTP
    id s09u95VoQgCqnWJ62_6_Jw
    for <test-noj289t8t@srv1.mail-tester.com>;
    Thu, 07 Sep 2023 09:36:42.966 +0000 (UTC)
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=953f2f71d3cc057b35d2548e10420b0c12b9e8296557c5bdcb71f06a9ab3
Date: Thu, 07 Sep 2023 09:36:43 +0000 (UTC)
From: Generation Global <helpdesk@generation.global>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Subject: Confirm your email address and set your password
Message-ID: <s09u95VoQgCqnWJ62_6_Jw@geopod-ismtpd-5>
X-SG-EID: 
 =?us-ascii?Q?Xt7jwbpeS7ePvcb7wfzapY18feVwdv8y=2FNk3PHticMZ+mcfHuT+e1pqmHtpBqY?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?qPxn5Sxq7E=2F=2FKSRpy9073cWUxl+s9D4ldWzZtxi?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?BjIYIDiOEaSCFtP6GZmzY2G02sueFGVZCOX3huP?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?38lIdgS3cqafS6cPSP0dAfb+GPmoUtHmrx+oCkE?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?y7kHOCORoLpaYDeRHSxPjobmOiLM2YH7DGpteu=2F?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?rVMnDT2ycQs5AhdPeH=2FVVPcpVL=2FKoam6mm5rXE3?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?tl1pEsKdhSoiDdwhxuantJdXyQPpBmBxWSxd1Qg?= =?us-ascii?Q?nM4=3D?=
X-SG-ID: 
 =?us-ascii?Q?N2C25iY2uzGMFz6rgvQsb8fga5n54QRd+qJeKTHTMRl8SOyCCBCf3p5maOTknh?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?gtwazv1EA7ampdFt8T+QCumT2O+RNz7DUll=2FRZt?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?LIRdb9BI5nPn+Sv6n0WjfBvJc4yEbFDtfbPKLbB?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?3QsIUQOFB1ZIjZuCnD8yn3YULXOIhEzhE7lRGtK?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?aSOnEhCBgfv4XCMyoP2M4qmCDa70CPJ034eqczg?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?3bGcY7d4D6yI55Pr0=3D?=
To: test-noj289t8t@srv1.mail-tester.com
X-Entity-ID: T2i3yDP3SaZzBBKZ1DMPgA==

--953f2f71d3cc057b35d2548e10420b0c12b9e8296557c5bdcb71f06a9ab3
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Mime-Version: 1.0

Dear Student,

Thank you for registering your account on Generation Global. Now we
just need you to confirm your email address so you can get started on
our site. Please click on the link below to confirm your email address
and set your password:

Confirm email and set password
[https://adventure.generation.global/student/reset/56170/1694079401/kwUczgz=
A5WnAsFB66rNpo-MzNYEzZ7QBT5uqsUW5QE0]

If you have any questions please contact our support at
generation.global/support [https://generation.global/support].

The Generation Global Team

--953f2f71d3cc057b35d2548e10420b0c12b9e8296557c5bdcb71f06a9ab3
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Mime-Version: 1.0

<p>Dear Student,</p>
<p>
  Thank you for registering your account on Generation Global.
  Now we just need you to confirm your email address so you can get started=
 on our site.
  Please click on the link below to confirm your email address and set your=
 password:
</p>

<p><a href=3D"https://adventure.generation.global/student/reset/56170/16940=
79401/kwUczgzA5WnAsFB66rNpo-MzNYEzZ7QBT5uqsUW5QE0">Confirm email and set pa=
ssword</a></p>

<p>If you have any questions please contact our support at <a href=3D"https=
://generation.global/support">generation.global/support</a>.</p>

<p>The Generation Global Team</p>





<p><img alt=3D"Generation Global" src=3D"https://generation.global/android-=
chrome-192x192.png" style=3D"height:120px; width:120px" /></p>
<img src=3D"http://mail.generation.global/wf/open?upn=3DCGUeh9-2FN5rG1LZ-2B=
9pan7arSj-2Bi-2B25ICZny4hSCkMZ4rbSqMLteZiRPKm4CNWI44zwXM-2Ff2AmZJR4MvCiYPTn=
Go7LXnaq1lh0e9KJzkIYC-2B3RK5nlWSPSswcZdPr4m6Lhbhvsuq8sLsiLwbzfy0WGFpq3yp-2F=
pyCmCW8vvjP80Cp90SmhMoAfXn318qXjpv5gci6abl0VDtuzCB7xGU9CSvg1WCaXOENw124PU2b=
zghoPG5taQpR6Tl-2FRnGSbnYCJjy3AoANdwLKA-2FOvnVEZG5AcxYqVrTc9uvrWBRsdZoxvCjn=
GTZPQetMSfJiQMjDzgsGxqcwQMqLpHNk5ubYvXQDoCjk4OZxrJYRDzjsxSNCh90sfs56sFQgUre=
UC0T5d6OwpGDYF2J3KzgJxk2wzEPoWk-2B-2Bd75LrTx5lFim7B-2FLNePLLy1G9agM2QxA6WCg=
u7a8MD9HxNZ-2FLo5TDw23EvWsA-3D-3D" alt=3D"" width=3D"1" height=3D"1" border=
=3D"0" style=3D"height:1px !important;width:1px !important;border-width:0 !=
important;margin-top:0 !important;margin-bottom:0 !important;margin-right:0=
 !important;margin-left:0 !important;padding-top:0 !important;padding-botto=
m:0 !important;padding-right:0 !important;padding-left:0 !important;"/>
--953f2f71d3cc057b35d2548e10420b0c12b9e8296557c5bdcb71f06a9ab3--
```

Full details:
https://www.mail-tester.com/test-noj289t8t

**EDIT:** After doing another test I spotted an instance where apparently DMARC failed: https://www.mail-tester.com/test-tri7i0dx9&reloaded=1

I am not sure why that is because the email comes from the same exact IP address of the email that passed DMARC so I am struggling to understand what's wrong.

Any thoughts on why they're being flagged as spam?

Comment: The average monthly spam reports % is between 0% and 0.01%

Comment: One of your trace headers (`Received: by filterdrecv-…`) looks odd. They are not supposed to have [standard times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), the format is instead the one from [5322](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.3).

Answer (score 0):

Any email service provider has their own secret recipe for detecting spam - SPF, DKIM and DMARC play a part in this but they only VALIDATE THE ORIGIN of the email. None of the providers will tell you exactly how their rules work for 2 reasons:

- it makes it easier for spammers to bypass the rules
- the providers often don't know how some their filters work

So nobody can answer your question.

You are doing the right things (although your RMX is a bit hokey - OTOH - you can't change this since its controlled by Sendgrid + Sendgrid's hosting / RMX is deprecated despite some providers still using it).

The only thing I notice here which **might** help the IPR is to add an [unsubscribe header](https://mailtrap.io/blog/list-unsubscribe-header/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @symcbean. It's so weird! Could it also be some of the words included in the email? Because this only seems to happen with the sign up verification email (that includes a link that users need to click on to verify their email)... I also checked on Google's Postmaster tools and both the domain and IP Reputation are high!

Comment: Ah I noticed something @symcbean, I was doing another test and this time (without changing anything in Sendgrid), DMARC failed: https://www.mail-tester.com/test-tri7i0dx9&reloaded=1 I don't know why that is...

Comment: Most likely the cause of your problem here.

Comment: How can the DKIM signature be valid one time and invalid the other though... it's managed by SendGrid

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes. Make sure you include the full headers from the failed and successful reports when you log a fault with them.